# Accessing a Scala Trait method inside another method

Tags: scala

I am writing a trait that contains a function:

```
trait MyTrait[X,Y] {
  def f(x : X) : Y
}
```

I'm trying to add a map function:

```
trait MyTrait[X,Y] {
  def f(x : X) : Y // the outer f

  def map[Z](g : Y => Z) : MyTrait[X,Y] = MyTrait[X,Z] {
    //namespace conflict : I need to access the outer f within this f
    override def f(x : X) : Z = outerF andThen g  
  }
}
```

**My question is: how do I reference the outer `f`?**  I've tried `super.f` and `this.f` to no avail.  I'm sure this is a basic question that has been asked before but it's not very "google-able", e.g. easy to search for.

thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self` type

```
trait MyTrait[X,Y] {
  self => 
  def f(x : X) : Y // the outer f

  def map[Z](g : Y => Z) : MyTrait[X,Y] = MyTrait[X,Z] {
    override def f(x : X) : Z = self.f andThen g  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to make a minor edit to get your example compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `override def f(x : X) : Z = MyTrait.this.f andThen g`.